# How can I determine the width of characters on the screen?

Tags: faces, fonts

Specifically, I'm interested in the width of characters in the default font assuming that the default font is mono-spaced.  From reading the documentation, I got the impression that this should give me the correct value:

```
(aref (font-info (face-font 'default)) 2)
```

However, these values are consistently too big.  For example, my current default font is

```
-unknown-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
```

and the code above gives me 13.  However, when I make a screenshot and measure the characters their width is only 8 pixels.  `frame-char-width`gives me 8 pixels but if I change the default font size (using `text-scale-increase`) it continues to say 8, so that isn't useful.

I'm working with Emacs 25.0.50.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: From the doc of `font-info`, the resulting array contains `MAX-WIDTH`, `SPACE-WIDTH`, `AVERAGE-WIDTH`, which should be same for a mono font. Does `(aref (font-info ...) 7)` gives you the correct result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the complete solution for my original problem.  Thanks to @jch and @Malabarba for contributing the crucial pieces.

```
(defun default-font-width () 
  "Return the width in pixels of a character in the current
window's default font.  More precisely, this returns the
width of the letter ‘m’.  If the font is mono-spaced, this
will also be the width of all other printable characters."
  (let ((window (selected-window))
        (remapping face-remapping-alist))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
      (setq face-remapping-alist remapping)
      (set-window-buffer window (current-buffer))
      (insert "m")
      (aref (aref (font-get-glyphs (font-at 1) 1 2) 0) 4))))
```

Update: This discussion led to the addition of three new functions in Emacs 25: `default-font-width`, `window-font-width`, and `window-font-height` (`default-font-height` was already part of emacs). `window-font-width` and `window-font-height` can be used to calculate the width and height or arbitrary faces.

Answer (score 8):

The second element of the font-info is the font's pixelsize, which is (roughly speaking) its height.  Getting the width of any particular glyph in the font is a little more work:

```
(aref (aref (font-get-glyphs (font-at (point)) 65 66) 0) 4)
```

Comment: While this answers my question (thank you!), I realize that my question wasn't precise enough.  Given a face, I'd like to know how much horizontal space a character would take if I'd insert it in the buffer.  Using your approach, I could insert the character in the buffer, measure it, and remove it.  However, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require any modifications in the buffer.  Is that possible?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I doubt it's possible in general -- I suspect the font hasn't been instantiated before it is displayed.

Comment: @tmalsburg use a temp buffer. But I'm not sure how they interact with fonts.

Comment: @jch do you have a link or something explaining where this information can be found. The solution is fine, but it's a little cryptic on its own.

Comment: @Malabarba, the only source I'm aware of is the docstring of `font-get-glyphs`.

Comment: When I put the caret at an English Letter it returns 8 and at a Chinese character it's 5. But the Chinese characters are apparently wider. Is it even correct?